# How do i get array at $_GET with javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, filter

How can I get an array like this

```
index.php?jenis=11,12,13
```

or like this without remove the previous value?

```
index.php?jenis=11&jenis=12&jenis=13
```

In my code wherever I do a click or an action it just get the next `$_GET` value but not keep the previous `$_GET` value. The question is how I can keep both previous `$_GET` and next `$_GET` into one?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="filter">
<label>Pertama </label>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="11" <?php if ($jenis == "11")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 11 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="12" <?php if ($jenis == "12")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 12 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="13" <?php if ($jenis == "13")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 13 </a> </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (!isset($_GET['jenis'])) {
    $jenis =  "";       
} else {
    $jenis = $_GET['jenis'];                            
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
        function jeniss(){
        document.getElementById('filter').submit(); 
        }           
</script>
```

Note : I'm using javascript so every action (check or uncheck) will redirect into new page which is my hope result. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Typing “php get array” into Google was all it took to find this duplicate right away. Please make more of an actual research effort next time.

Answer (score 2):

Name your inputs with `[]` to append multiple values

`name="jenis[]"`

then you should be able to acces the array using a loop

```
foreach($_GET['jenis'] as $jenis) {echo $jenis}
```

or in your case use the in_array() function

```
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="11" <?php if (in_array("11",$_POST['jenis'])  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 11 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="12" <?php if (in_array("12",$_POST['jenis'])  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 12 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="13" <?php if (in_array("13",$_POST['jenis'])  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 13 </a> </li>
```

Comment: srry for disturbing. can u tell me which part of my php should change or add with the foreach ?. Or can u edit ur answer and add ur own php code, i'm just beginner and little confuse. Thx for helping

Comment: use the last snippet in my answer and you should be set

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your input's value as previous + actual value of your GET parameter.

```
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="<?php echo $jenis.',11'?>" <?php if ($jenis == "11")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 11 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="<?php echo $jenis.',12'?>" <?php if ($jenis == "12")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 13 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis" value="<?php echo $jenis.',13'?>" <?php if ($jenis == "13")  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 12 </a> </li>
```

This will output as you first said in your post: `,11,12,13` (first comma is when `$jenis` is empty. You can ignore it when explodin array for commas)